# What does this handwritten note mean?

Tags: meaning

I own a book by Giuseppe Peano where some notes were written in Italian by the previous owner.
However I can't read one of those.

[image: note]

I just know that the note starts with (1), that the underlined word is *formale*.
I also recognise *morfologia* and *linguistico*.

**Edit:** The first line is "Doppio senso del termine formale" and mean "double meaning of the term formal" (@Charo)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! The first line says "Doppio senso del termine *formale*", that is, double meaning of the term *formal*. In the second line, I only recognize "de forma" (from *form*) and "morfologia".

Comment: That's a good starting point, thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe "tracta de forma" if that makes sense

Comment: Under “senso” there is an “a” and under it a “b”, followed by something that seems to be in “Latino sine flexione” (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latino_sine_flexione).

Comment: The Peano book I was referring to is entirely written in LsF but morfologia is clearly Italian (in LsF, ph is used for greek words), for a and b, I think that you are right

Comment: Blatantly off-topic, but it says “tracta de forma de vocabulo linguistico” (in LsF), with added “morfologia” (in Italian) in parentheses.

Comment: Yes it is also what I just find out, indeed the last part appears to be off-topic, of course I did not know that when posting

Answer (score 2):

After considering all the comments, I think I came up with the solution, which is half Italian and half Latino sine Flexione.

```
(1) Doppio senso del termine formale
                             -------
             a
             b) tracta de forma de vocabulo (morfologia)
                         linguistico
```